# Does data repartition happen when changing keys on Kafka Streams but pushing to new topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm reading Filebeat Json documents off a a central topic.

Filtering based on the file source/path

flatMap the message field which is an encoded Json and serializing that to Json and extracting the key (yes I know potentially I can have json decode exceptions here, I will output empty record for this).

Push to a new topic.

---

If the message parsed correctly and I got the key and output that to a new topic, will it cause a repartition?

Basically I'm doing a stateless "move/copy" to a separate topic.

Comment: Why would the source topic be repartitioned?

Comment: Just asking, cause I'm new to this... Basically I have a a topic which receives all logs from all applications. It's 18 partitions and I plan to have various consumers/streams read and filter for the specified applications and push to their own topics.

Comment: The input topic isn't altered. There might be some intermediate topic, or the output topic has differerent partitioning than the input

Comment: `If the message parsed correctly and I got the key and output that to a new topic, will it cause a repartition?` -- not 100% sure what you mean by this. When data is written into the result topic, it will be partitioned by the new key by default. But there won't be any additional repartitioning steps.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Thats what I though. I'm fine with that. I'm strictly using it as a simple Json transform and copy to new topic.

Comment: @cricket_007 to do join maybe? I am working with similar use case right now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `selectKey(...)` and publishing the result KStream, it doesn't repartition the stream.

It might result in an internal data redistribution if a key based operator (like an aggregation or join) is applied to the result KStream.

Comment: `it doesn't repartition the stream` -- well, but when the output topic is written, it will be partitioned by the new key....